# Matching pattern multiple times on text file?

Tags: java, regex, string

### The Problem:

In Java, I will be parsing scripts and extracting any text from the file that begins with

```
    ${GLOBAL_} or ${AUTO_}
```

I want to pickup everything until the last curly brace, so for example if I had the following String:

```
    "this is a String ${AUTO_TEST_f} body ${GLOBAL_SYNC} ${AUTO_2} ${OTHER_VAR}"
```

The results should be:

```
${AUTO_TEST_f} 

${GLOBAL_SYNC}

${AUTO_2}
```

### What I've Attempted:

I've attempted to create regex patterns (that I believe do work) and using them to create a Matcher.  I then attempt to use the Matcher to print all the matches to console but I'm having some issues.  For some reason, it's skipping over ${GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1}. Also, how could I implement this to give me all the matches? A while loop [while match.group(0) != null]?

Here's my code:

```
 String re1="(\\$)";    // Any Single Character 1
String re2="(\\{)"; // Any Single Character 2
String re3="(G)";   // Any Single Character 3
String re4="(L)";   // Any Single Character 4
String re5="(O)";   // Any Single Character 5
String re6="(B)";   // Any Single Character 6
String re7="(A)";   // Any Single Character 7
String re8="(L)";   // Any Single Character 8
String re9="(_)";   // Any Single Character 9
String re10="(.*?)";    // Any Single Character 10
String re11="(\\})";    // Any Single Character 11


String r1="(\\$)";  // Any Single Character 1
String r2="(\\{)";  // Any Single Character 2
String r3="(A)";    // Any Single Character 3
String r4="(U)";    // Any Single Character 4
String r5="(T)";    // Any Single Character 5
String r6="(O)";    // Any Single Character 6
String r7="(_)";    // Any Single Character 7
String r8="(.*?)";  // Any Single Character 8
String r9="(\\})";  // Any Single Character 9

Pattern p = Pattern.compile((re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11));
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9);

 Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
 Matcher m1 = p2.matcher(txt);
 m1.find();
 System.out.println(m1.group(0));
 m.find();
 System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

And this is the Console Results:

```
 Actual Results:
 ${AUTO_1}
 ${GLOBAL_VARIABLE_2}
```

Here are my expected Results:

```
 Expected Results:
 ${GLOBAL_VARIABLE_1}
 ${AUTO_1}
 ${GLOBAL_VARIABLE_2}
 ${GLOBAL_VARIABLE_3}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate:

```
String txt = "this is a String ${AUTO_TEST_f} body ${GLOBAL_SYNC} ${AUTO_2}";
String regex = "\\$\\{(AUTO|GLOBAL)_(.*?)\\}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txt);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group() + "\t->\t" + matcher.group(2) + "\t(" + matcher.group(1) + ")" );
}
```

Output:

```
${AUTO_TEST_f}  ->  TEST_f  (AUTO)
${GLOBAL_SYNC}  ->  SYNC    (GLOBAL)
${AUTO_2}       ->  2       (AUTO)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
String data = "this is a String ${AUTO_TEST_f} body ${GLOBAL_SYNC} ${AUTO_2}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{.+?\\}");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        // Indicates match is found. Do further processing
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Output is :

${AUTO_TEST_f}
${GLOBAL_SYNC}
${AUTO_2}

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are doing, it is not the right way to code. Composing a regex from smaller components is fine, but it is pointless when you break the component down to single character.

If you want to get those that starts with `GLOBAL` or `AUTO`, it is as simple as:

```
\$\{(GLOBAL|AUTO)_.*?\}
```

Putting the regex into a string literal:

```
"\\$\\{(GLOBAL|AUTO)_.*?\\}"
```